# HTML Superscript to Plain Text with PHP

Tags: php, type-conversion, superscript

I am working on converting HTML document to plain text by striping and replacing all the HTML tags and succeed in doing so. But i have come across this situation where i need to handle the superscript. I have this HTML code :

11,500m<sup>²</sup>

(suppose there are sup tag shown above, but i don't know how to show them here)
I need to convert it to plain text so that it will become just 11,500m². How can i do so? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you need....you have this HTML code `11,500m²` (which is just a simple string and no html...) and you want to get `11,500m²` (wich is the same thing).

Comment: i mentioned above, suppose there are sup tag shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are only a few superscript numbers in [ASCII](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/superscript-one-exponent-1-first-power-ascii-code-251.html).

```
// replace all ... things to a power of 1
str_replace("<sup>1</sup>", "¹", $html)
// replace all squares
str_replace("<sup>2</sup>", "²", $html)
// replace all cubes
str_replace("<sup>3</sup>", "³", $html)
// for everything else use ^ notation
str_replace("<sup>", "^", $html)
// remove leftover closing sup tags
str_replace("</sup>", "", $html)
```

As there is no way in plain text to have most characters this solution will:

Find text like: Some Text<sup>Other</sup>

And output:     Some Text^Other

Comment: It works fine, except for the "^" notation. How to handle for example <sup>Other</sup> ?

Comment: Updated answer to explain.

Comment: Thank you for marking as answer but a up vote is always nice too :)